# object movement as wave in Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, monodevelop, unityscript

I created a object in unity

```
GameObject monsterclone = 
      (GameObject)Instantiate(monsterPrefab, floorPosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

This object should move in a wave style from a limit1 to limit2.

Then move back from limit2 to limit1.

Y position as well x position have to change in a specific way.

```
Vector3 nPos = mfloorPos + new Vector3(2f, 0f, 0f);
Vector3 oPos = mfloorPos  + new Vector3(-2f, 0f, 0f);
```

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: what's happening with the code above? Instead of a gameObject, did you try creating a transform.

Comment: This question needs some clarification - What kind of wave must the object move in, is it a Sin wave, a consistent Saw wave movement or a diminishing bouncing movement? The picture isn't clear enough to see what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float amplitudeX = -25.0f;
float amplitudeY = 5.0f;
float omegaX = 0.5f;
float omegaY = 4.0f;
float index;

void Update () {
    index += Time.deltaTime;
    float x = amplitudeX*Mathf.Cos (omegaX*index);      
    float y = Mathf.Abs (amplitudeY*Mathf.Sin (omegaY*index));
    if(transform.position.x > 24){
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(270, -90, 0);
    }
    if(transform.position.x < -24){
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(270, 90, 0);
    }   
    transform.localPosition= new Vector3(x,y,20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly write the code without knowing more specific but i think this question is already asked any this link will help you out [MOVE OBJECT as wave](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/59934/how-to-an-object-floating-up-and-down.html)

**EDIT:**

I think the flat up and float down functionality will work for you  for moving one point to another
example:

```
var floatup;
function Start(){
floatup = false;
}
function Update(){
if(floatup)
floatingup();
else if(!floatup)
floatingdown();
}
function floatingup(){
transform.position.y += 0.3 * Time.deltaTime;
yield WaitForSeconds(1);
floatup = false;
}
function floatingdown(){
transform.position.y -= 0.3 * Time.deltaTime;;
yield WaitForSeconds(1);
floatup = true;
}
```

[example taken from](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/59934/how-to-an-object-floating-up-and-down.html)

Comment: By moving y position how can we make wave. i already searched and gone through these answers. request you write working answers

Comment: it will go up and down. for that i can just use pingpong. But i want to move x positions also.. i edited question with a image

Answer (score 0):

If this is a consitant wave and not dependant on speed I would use an animation to create a literal wave curve of the Position.Y value (much in the same principle as Ravindra Shekhawat has explained.) you can find out more about animation [here.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/AnimationEditorGuide.html)

Here is some code (untested) that you could go off. It is in c# so I hope it proves no issue with putting in to JavaScript.

```
bool monsterMoving = false;

void Update(){
    //check monster moving to start updating position
    if(monsterMoving == true){

        //moving animation controls up and down "wave" movement
        animation.CrossFade('moving'); 

        //Lerp changes position
        Transform.Lerp(transform.Position, oPos, Time.deltaTime); 

        if (transform.Position == oPos) {
            //We are at destination, stop movement
            monsterMoving = false;
        }

    } else {
        // if monster stopped moving, return to idle animation (staying still)
        animation.CrossFade('idle');
    }
}

// function to send a new position to the monster object
void MoveTo(Vector3 newPos){
    oPos = newPos;
    monsterMoving = true;
}
```

Comment: "hope u didn't get my question"? Not sure I understand what you mean there. This solution would produce the effects that you described in the question before it was edited. A transform function between the two points on Update() and the animation creating an Up and Down movement would solve the issue of your object bobbing up and down in a wave while your object moved from A to B. It may not fit your solution after your edit with the picture above but you need to clearly explain your answer first time around so we can help answer more clearly.